# Для чего используется IP-адрес 127.0.1.1?

Tags: ubuntu, ip, hosts

В Ubuntu с именем компьютера сопоставляется адрес `127.0.1.1`. Для чего он используется?

Comment: Это позволяет, например, развернуть DNS-сервер на 127.0.1.1 и в то же время разрешить пользователю поднять свой DNS-сервер на 127.0.0.1

Comment: иногда бывает нужно локально потестить кластер (группу серверов) и каждому нужен свой апйи. А если ещё хочется очень много подключений... то без этого уже никак не обойтись - ведь если подключаться с 127.0.0.1 на 127.0.0.1, то получиться максимум 32к соединений...

Comment: Как пример: для реализации нескольких локальных веб-сайтов с HTTPS. Если бы был один адрес 127.0.0.1. Пришлось бы каждому сайту использовать разный порт вместо 443. А так можно раскидать по разным адресам.

Answer (score 17):

Это [частный](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_IP-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81) IP-адрес, который **не** зависит от ОС.

Используется для создания методов [обратной петли](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback), т. е. чтобы можно было обратиться к "себе" (`источник == получатель`), без надобности узнавания точного "своего" адреса и/или использования особых методов доступа к "себе".

Интересной особенностью является то, что его обслуживает драйвер **псевдо**устройства в ядре ОС, что позволяет использовать сеть на этот адрес без наличия хоть какой-то сети и даже сетевой карты.

Использование ограничено лишь фантазией, к примеру - локальный сервер или редирект ссылок хостов проверки легальности на локалку, где отвечают что всё в порядке :)

Comment: Почему для этого `localhost` не подходит?

Comment: `localhost` - доменное имя для `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Я в курсе. Для описанных вами вещей подходит и `127.0.0.1`, так зачем использовать `127.0.1.1`

Comment: @jisecayeyo да там целая подсеть класса A выделена для этой цели... На заре интернета адресов не жалели.

Comment: @jisecayeyo, обновил. Правду сказал Pavel Mayorov: древние верили в две вещи: мамонт - это вкусно и в то, что `IPv4` хватит **очень** надолго.

Comment: @Other а еще не очень древний мамонт вещал, что "640 кб оперативной памяти должно хватить всем" :) людям свойственно ошибаться )

Comment: @Crystal тогда люди явно уделяли время на размышления другим интересным вещам: самка - в пещеру - цензура; мамонт - охота - валим!; ога - ары - шта. Где тут подумать о глобальности задумки? Тем более такой масштаб банально не поместится в такой оперативке для расчёта ситуации.

Answer (score 7):

ipv4-адрес `127.0.1.1` в современных операционных системах используется для того же самого, что и все ipv4-адреса из диапазона `127.0.0.0-127.255.255.255` (в терминах современной [безклассовой адресации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) — `127/8`) — для обращения к [локальному компьютеру](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) по протоколу [ipv4](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4).

> Почему для этого localhost не подходит?

ещё как «подходит»! в один из этих 16777216 (2^24) ipv4-адресов обычно и резолвится имя `localhost` (практически везде — в `127.0.0.1`). а резолвить, конечно, надо — ведь обращение по протоколу ipv4 должно происходить не по имени, а по ipv4-адресу.

Comment: Почему возникает необходимость использовать `127.0.1.1`, вместо `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: @jisecayeyo никакой необходимости нет, вот просто так хочется

Comment: @jisecayeyo, нужный для приложения порт на `127.0.0.1` уже может быть занят.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, в дополнение к другим ответам, хочу отметить, что данная настройка в Ubuntu **позволяет проверить доступность (или задать правила доступа) по доменному имени**.

Так, настроив вебсервер для обращения по 127.0.0.1 и запретив обращение по 127.0.1.1 можно проверить различные ситуации доступа как по IP так и по доменному имени.

Так же это позволяет по умолчанию иметь два имени и логически разделять их.